# Oracle: Merge equivalent of insert all?

Tags: oracle, merge

I've tried to find an answer on several forums with no luck, so perhaps you can help me out.
I've got an INSERT ALL request that inserts thousands of rows at once.

```
INSERT ALL
   INTO my_table (field_x, field_y, field_z) VALUES ('value_x1', 'value_y1', 'value_z1')
   INTO my_table (field_x, field_y, field_z) VALUES ('value_x2', 'value_y2', 'value_z2')
   ...
   INTO my_table (field_x, field_y, field_z) VALUES ('value_xn', 'value_yn', 'value_zn')
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Now I'd like to amend it to update rows when some criteria are met. For each row, I could have something like:

```
MERGE INTO my_table m
    USING (SELECT 'value_xi' x, 'value_yi' y, 'value_zi' z FROM DUAL) s
    ON (m.field_x = s.x and m.field_y = s.y)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
        field_z = s.z,
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THE INSERT (field_x, field_y, field_z) 
        VALUE(s.x, s.y, s.z);
```

Is there a way for me to do a kind of "MERGE ALL" that would allow to have all those merge requests in one?

Or maybe I'm missing the point and there's a better way to do this?

Thanks,

Edit: One possible solution is to use "UNION ALL" for a set of selects from dual, as follows:

```
MERGE INTO my_table m
    USING (
        select '' as x, '' as y, '' as z from dual
        union all select 'value_x1', 'value_y1', 'value_z1' from dual
        union all select 'value_x2', 'value_y2', 'value_z2' from dual
        [...]
        union all select 'value_xn', 'value_yn', 'value_zn' from dual
    ) s
    ON (m.field_x = s.x and m.field_y = s.y)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET 
        field_z = s.z,
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (field_x, field_y, field_z) 
        VALUES (s.x, s.y, s.z);
```

NB: I've used a first empty row to be able generate all rows in the same format when I write the request. I also specify the columns names there.

Another solution would be to create a temporary table, INSERT ALL data into it, then merge with the target table and delete the temporary table.

Comment: There isn't a Merge equivalent of Insert All, so if you want to do upsert-style instead, you need to do a merge statement per table.

Comment: Thanks Boneist. When you say I need to do a merge statement per table, do you mean I need to use two tables in my merge request (rather than having raw data as described above) or that I can define a "merge" function for the table my_table that would automatically update pre-existing rows when I run an INSERT ALL request? Because I won't be creating a new table just for that, at most I'll start by deleting existing entries and then running the INSERT ALL query...  :/

Comment: Hmm, I may have misunderstood what you meant. Please can you update your question to include the sample data you're trying to insert/merge? I.e. is it coming from another table, or as an array or something else?

Comment: No worries, I should have used quotes around the values to show those were "hard coded". In fact, I've just been suggested using set of select from dual with union all to get the input. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Where are you getting the data you're trying to insert/merge in the first place? Is it being passed into a procedure from a non-db calling procedure (e.g. a front end application), or are you getting it from tables in the database?

Comment: From a non DB related python script, that's what was my problem.

Comment: Then I'd go with either using the `select ... union all` solution you mentioned or creating a GTT (global temporary table) once, and then inserting the data from the python script there, and using that in your merge statement (you don't need to drop and recreate it each time, then). It kind of depends on how much data you're expecting from the python script (a large `select ... union all` query might take a long time to parse), how the data is being passed across (all in one go, row by row, etc) etc. I am assuming that this is a regularly run process, btw.

Comment: It would run once a week. I'm expecting tens of thousands of rows that would all be calculated by the script and then pushed to DB. I prefered the select ... union all solution to avoid creating a temporary table, but if performance are going to be terrible, I might change my mind...

Comment: You would only need to create the GTT once, though. With tens of thousands of rows, I'd opt for the GTT method.

Comment: OK fair enough :) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're passing in tens of thousands of rows from your python script, I would do:

1. Create a global temporary table (GTT - this is a permanent table that holds data at session level)
2. Get your python script to insert the rows into the GTT
3. Use the GTT in the Merge statement, e.g.:

```
merge into your_main_table tgt
  using your_gtt src
    on (<join conditions>)
when matched then
  update ...
when not matched then
  insert ...;
```